# Mapping nested array inside mapped array in React JSX

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to write a dashboard sidebar which has a couple of "primary" buttons which (via Bootstrap) collapse a number of "secondary" buttons. I want to be able to easily update and style the whole thing so writing static markup is out of the picture. Here is one object out of the array:

```
const menuArray = [
{
  primaryText: "Applications",
  primaryIcon: "fa fa-rocket",
  primaryURL: "/applications",
  secondaries: [
    {
      secondaryText: "Softwares",
      secondaryURL: "/softwares",
    },
    {
      secondaryText: "Videogames",
      secondaryURL: "/videogames",
    },
    {
      secondaryText: "Tools",
      secondaryURL: "/tools",
    },
  ],
},
]
```

And here is the function rendering the array which i'm simply calling in the JSX markup by {renderMenuArray}

```
const renderMenuArray = menuArray.map((menuItem) => (
<li className="py-2">
  <button
    data-target={`#${menuItem.primaryText}Submenu`}
    data-toggle="collapse"
    aria-expanded="false"
    className="btn btn-dark btn-menu btn-block pl-0 mb-1"
  >
    <Link to={menuItem.primaryURL}>
      <span className="mr-3">
        <i className={menuItem.primaryIcon}></i>
      </span>
      {menuItem.primaryText}
    </Link>
  </button>

  <div
    className="card-body collapse ml-5"
    id={`${socialItem.primaryText}Submenu`}
  >
    <ul className="list-unstyled">
      <li>
        <Link className="small" to="/applications/softwares">
          <span className="mr-3">
            <i className="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
          </span>
          Softwares
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
));
```

I can render the "primary" objects with no problem at all, but I want each "primary" object ( each iteration of the parent array) to each iterate through the count of "secondaries" array ( which is going to be different for each "primary" object).

I'm a beginner developer.

Comment: You should show where/how you are trying to render the `secondaries` array for each item. It should just be a case of running `menuItem.secondaries.map((subItem) => ...)` inside the main block.

Comment: @lawrence-witt Thank you so much, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object passed into the callback function for the map, `menuItem` has the included property `secondaries`. You can use map on this property since `secondaries` is an array, simply place the map inside of your JSX.

```js
<div
    className="card-body collapse ml-5"
    id={`${socialItem.primaryText}Submenu`}
  >
    <ul className="list-unstyled">
      {menuItem.secondaries.map((subItem) => {
        ...
      })

    </ul>
</div>
```

P.S. you forgot to close your last div tag, and you have a second `</li>` instead of a `</ul>`

Answer (score 0):

This'll work (made it a bit more functional, to give you an example of what's possible with functional React components)

```
const menuArray = [
  {
    primaryText: "Applications",
    primaryIcon: "fa fa-rocket",
    primaryURL: "/applications",
    secondaries: [
      {
        secondaryText: "Softwares",
        secondaryURL: "/softwares"
      },
      {
        secondaryText: "Videogames",
        secondaryURL: "/videogames"
      },
      {
        secondaryText: "Tools",
        secondaryURL: "/tools"
      }
    ]
  }
];

export default function App(props) {
  function renderSecondaryMenu(items) {
    return items.map(secondaryItem => {
      return (
        <li>
          <Link className="small" to={secondaryItem.secondaryURL}>
            <span className="mr-3">
              <i className="fa fa-chevron-right" />
            </span>
            {secondaryItem.secondaryText}
          </Link>
        </li>
      );
    });
  }

  function renderMenuArray() {
    return menuArray.map(menuItem => {
      return (
        <li className="py-2">
          <button
            data-target={`#${menuItem.primaryText}Submenu`}
            data-toggle="collapse"
            aria-expanded="false"
            className="btn btn-dark btn-menu btn-block pl-0 mb-1"
          >
            <Link to={menuItem.primaryURL}>
              <span className="mr-3">
                <i className={menuItem.primaryIcon} />
              </span>
              {menuItem.primaryText}
            </Link>
          </button>

          <div
            className="card-body collapse ml-5"
            id={`${menuItem.primaryText}Submenu`}
          >
            <ul className="list-unstyled">
              {renderSecondaryMenu(menuItem.secondaries)}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      );
    });
  }

  return <div className="App">{renderMenuArray()}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you gain a lot from defining the sidebar as an object, unless you are using the same Sidebar component with different sets of buttons and you wanna be able to switch between them. JSX is already a markup language, so it's declarative.
You could define simply the Sidebar as

```
const Sidebar = () => (
  <PrimaryItem text="Applications" icon="fa fa-rocket" url="/applications">
    <SecondaryItem text="Softwares" url="/softwares" />
    <SecondaryItem text="Videogames" url="/videogames" />
    <SecondaryItem text="Tools" url="/tools" />
  </PrimaryItem>
)
```

And then implement each component as you need to display them. I think this is cleaner and easier to maintain and modify.

Comment: I'm thinking about fetching the sidebar items from the database based on user access level but i don't know how effective it's going to be. What you're suggesting is definitely an interesting and more modular approach, I will definitely try it out.